# Помогите, пожалуйста, подруге из-за границы :)

Tags: орфография, грамматика

**Привет!**
Меня завут Марта, и я живу в Польше. Я изучаю русский язык, и у меня скоро будет экзамен. Мне надо будет написать разработку по теме *"что такое спорт?"*. И у меня ест вопрос: вы могли бы мне помочь и указать на ошибки или добавить что-то, чтобы это звучило профессионально и хорошо? :)
Очень спасибо!

**А здесь текст:**

В последнее время спорт это прежде всего мода. Почти все женщины хотелы бы выгладеть как Эва Ходаковска* и вести здоровый образ жизнии который не только помогает похудеть но даже являются источником красоты. Здоровая кожа и стройная фигура поднимает настроение. а упражнения снимает чувство усталости. сонливость и даже обогащает жизнь и закаляет волю.

Спорт должен быть спутником каждого человека на протяжений всей его жизни. Многие физические недостатки и недуги поддаются лечению спортом. Это способ, требующий не дорогостоящих  лекарственных препаратов и технических приспособлений, а только воли и некоторых усилий над собой.  Здесь следует подчеркнуть, что нет здорового образа жизни без cбалансированной диеты. Но как говорят  - “если нельзя, а очень хочеться, то можно”- но всё с умом! Один кусочек шоколада или бокал вина будет идеальным дополнением ежедневного питания.

Важно отметить, что спорт даёт ощущение плеча друга и это особенно касается командных видов спорта, как примерно футбол или хоккей. Это хороший и интересный способ на проводение времени с друзьями, улучшение координации и настроения. Необходимо подчеркнуть при этом, что зимние виды спорта особо хорошо влияет на самочувствие – поправляют кровоснабжение и обеспечивают кислородом все ткании организма.  В качестве примера можно даже привести бесспорного лидера омолаживающих занятий – танцы. Движения под нагрузку нормализуют гормональный фон, a отдельные виды танца это прекрасный массаж внутренных органов. Вместе с тем стоит иметь в виду, что физзарядка и бег трусцой, теннис и бадминтон принесут пользу в летнее время.

Суммируя сказанное выше, следует отметить, что спорт даёт лёгкость мысли и образов, помогает решить множество проблем и даже хорошо влияет на наш организм - восстановливает ресусы и укрепляет его. Это самый лучший способ продления жизни и молодости или просто ежедневное улучшение настроения. В здоровом теле – здоровый дух!

*Эва Ходаковска* это известная фитнес-тренер из Польши :)

И как Вам нравится? :)

Comment: Марта, а вы не могли бы дать ссылку или написать, как на самом деле называется методика пани Эвы? Везде переводят "для похудания", это совсем не то, что "поддерживать оптимальный вес". Как это по-польски будет?

Comment: @behemothus Skalpel и Killer они называются. И еще куча безымянных. Это не методики, это разные комплексы под разную "целевую аудиторию" и разный уровень подготовленности. От простого к сложному, но на каждом уровне можно выбирать из нескольких предлагаемых курсов.  Но согласен, это именно сгонка веса и набор формы. Для поддержания - слишком жестоко. Очень интенсивный метод.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 3):

В последнее время спорт - это прежде всего мода. Почти все женщины хотели бы выглядеть как Эва Ходаковска* и вести здоровый образ жизни, сохраняющий **оптимальный** вес, являющийся источником красоты. Здоровая кожа и стройная фигура поднимают настроение, а физические упражнения  снимают сонливость и чувство усталости, закаляют волю и в целом обогащают нашу жизнь.

Спорт должен быть спутником каждого человека на протяжении всей его жизни. Многие физические недостатки и недуги лечатся спортом. Этот способ требует не дорогостоящих лекарственных препаратов и технических приспособлений, а только воли и некоторых усилий над собой. Также следует подчеркнуть,  что нет здорового образа жизни без cбалансированной, но разумной  диеты. Как говорят, “если нельзя, а очень хочется, то можно”, но всё с умом! Один кусочек шоколада или бокал вина будет **хорошим** дополнением ежедневного правильного питания.

Важно отметить, что спорт даёт ощущение плеча друга, и это в первую очередь касается командных видов спорта, как например футбол или хоккей. Это хороший и интересный способ  не только проведения времени с друзьями, но и улучшения координации тела, повышения настроения.

Подходящий вид спортивных занятий можно найти для себя в любое время года. Зимние виды спорта **особенно** хорошо влияют на самочувствие – улучшают кровоснабжение и обеспечивают кислородом все ткани организма, а физзарядка и бег трусцой, теннис и бадминтон принесут вам пользу в летнее время. Также в качестве примера можно  привести бесспорного лидера омолаживающих занятий – танцы. Движения под нагрузку нормализуют гормональный фон, a отдельные виды танцевальных движений - это прекрасный массаж внутренних органов.

В заключение можно сказать, что спорт даёт нам лёгкость мыслей и чувств, помогает решить множество проблем и, конечно,  влияет на  наш организм - восстанавливает его ресурсы и укрепляет его. Это самый лучший способ для продления жизни и молодости или просто ежедневного улучшения настроения. В здоровом теле – здоровый дух!

Comment: Мне понравилась ваша статья, Марта.  Вы очень убедительно рассказали  нам о пользе спорта и здорового образа жизни.

Comment: Большое спасибо! :))

Comment: Мне нравится, как Вы переделали, Sibylla, поставил плюсик, хочу только пару моментов сказать. Очень мне не нравится слово "идеальный" (два раза по тексту). Разве идеал вообще достижим? Вообще никогда не понимал, как можно об идеале и идеальном всерьёз говорить. И "особо" Вы, видимо, проглядели, оставили; наверно, надо заменить на "особенно".

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, учла все Ваши замечания.

Comment: А я не в востроге. Вы забыли, что автор - человек со своим национальным менталитетом,  что язык не родной и что это не статья для слащавого дамского журнала. Во-первых, вы переделали стиль, во-вторых, по сути сделали домашнее задание. Если учитель что-то заподозрит, а он не может это не сделать, получив подобное, то результат будет совсем не тот, на который вы рассчитываете.  Я совсем не уверен, например, что полтская девушка подобно русской Дуне адекватно воспримет замену "красивой фигуры"  на "оптимальный вес". Да и кой вообще такая замена?! Короче, я бы не рекомендовал Марте ваш вариант.

Comment: Sibylla, мне тоже понравилась ваш редакция. Автор пишет хорошо, но в тексте были шероховатости, которые вы очень хорошо исправили.

Comment: @Серж, да некотрые вообще ничего понимают в межкультурных коммуникациях. Но зачем об этом сообщать иностранному студенту, который совершенно не за тем сюда пришел, чтоб в чужом грязном белье копаться?!

Answer (score 2):

Witamy panienku! 
Postaram się pomóc.

> или добавить что-то, чтобы это звучило профессионально и хорошо?

Профессионально - это вряд ли. Тут нет профессиональных журналистов, не то что преподавателей. В вот всё остальное - попробую. Я вам напишу краткие пояснения тех моментов, которые вам пригодятся, если что непонятно - спрашивайте, буду рад помочь.

Правописание и грамматика.

//------------

Помогите пожалуйста подруге из-за границы :)

Привет! Меня з**о**вут Марта**,** и я живу в Польш**е**. Я изучаю русский язык**,** и у меня скоро будет экзамен. Мне надо будет написать работу *[разработка здесь не по контексту]* по теме "**Ч**то такое спорт?". И у меня ест**ь** вопрос: **"Вы не** могли бы мне помочь и указать на ошибки или добавить что-то, чтобы это звуч**а**ло професси**о**нально и хорошо?**"** :) **Большое** спасибо! *["Очень спасибо" - англицизм, "спасибо" в русском - существительное, требует при себе прилагательного, не наречия.]*

А здесь текст:

В последнее время спорт **-** это прежде всего мода. Почти все женщины хотел**и** бы выгл**я**деть *[Марта, здесь в обоих случаях **L** мягкое, не **Ł** - поэтому **"ли"** и **"ля"**]* как Эва Ходаковска* и вести здоровый образ **жизни,** который не только помогает похудеть**,** но даже явля**е**тся источником красоты. Здоровая кожа и стройная фигура поднима**ю**т настроение**,** а упражнения снима**ю**т чувство усталости и сонливости и даже обогаща**ю**т жизнь и закаля**ю**т волю *[множественное число везде, грамматику престроил, у вас было что-то непонятное]*.

Спорт должен быть спутником каждого человека на протяжени**и** всей его жизни. Многие физические недостатки и недуги поддаются лечению спортом. Это способ, **не требующий** дорогостоящих лекарственных препаратов и технических приспособлений, **но** только воли и некоторых усилий над собой *[Ваш вариант стилистически плох, можно и по-другому поправить, лиже к вашему исходному, но править надо]*. Здесь следует вспомнить, что **не может быть** *[так понятнее]* здорового образа жизни без cбалансированной диеты. Как говорят, “если нельзя, а очень **хочется**, то можно” - но ко всему надо подходить с умом! *[У вас в одном предложении было два "но", это очень плохо понимается]*  Один кусочек шоколада или бокал вина буд**у**т *[plural!!!]* идеальным дополнением ежедневного питания.

Важно отметить, что спорт даёт ощущение плеча друга**,** и это особенно касается командных видов спорта, **таких как** *["как примерно" - это другой смысл]* футбол или хоккей. Это хороший и интересный способ **проводения** *[здесь требуется именно такое падежное управление - Genetiv без предлога. Это особый **приименной генетив**, аналог английcкого притяжательного "-'s", очень важен в русском, постарайтесь его выучить, хотя с ним бывает сложно даже носителям славянских языков, (кроме восточнославянских)]* времени с друзьями, улучшение координации и настроения. Необходимо подчеркнуть при этом, что зимние виды спорта особо хорошо влияет на самочувствие – поправляют кровоснабжение и обеспечивают кислородом все ткании организма. В качестве примера можно даже привести бесспорного лидера омолаживающих занятий – танцы. Движения под нагрузку нормализуют гормональный фон, a отдельные виды танца это прекрасный массаж внутренных органов. Вместе с тем стоит иметь в виду, что физзарядка и бег трусцой, теннис и бадминтон принесут пользу в летнее время.

Суммируя сказанное выше, следует отметить, что спорт даёт лёгкость мысли и образов, помогает решить множество проблем и даже хорошо влияет на наш организм - восстан**а**вливает *[чередование а/o в глаголах совершенного-несовершенного вида, сложная тема, это надо запомнить или проверять по словарю]* ресу**р**сы и укрепляет его. Это самый лучший способ продления жизни и молодости **и** *[в таких случаях в русском именно **И**, вы же не противопоставляете одно другому]* просто ежедневное улучшение настроения. В здоровом теле – здоровый дух!

*Эва Ходаковска **-** это известн**ый** *[здесь не нужно подчеркивать, что это дама, и так ясно]* фитнес-тренер из Польши :)

Понравилось ли вам? *[И как Вам нравится? - это стилизация, здесь не нужна. ]* :)

//------------

Вы хорошо пишете, вполне внятно. Это очень хороший уровень для изучающих РКИ (русский как иностранный). Ошибки есть, но они связаны, как я понимаю, с отсутствием практики по конкретным темам грамматики. Особенно - согласование глаголов во множественном числе. Посмотрите, эта тема не очень сложная.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой исчерпывающий ответ! Теперь я, конечно, получу пятёрку с плюсом! :)) И тоже мне надо добавить, что Ты это сделал как профессионалист! Извините за ошибки. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Да не за что. Я одну ошибку еще поправил.  И еще, Марта, в русском "Ты" никогда не пишется с заглавной (если это не начало предложения). А вообще на общедоступных форумах "ты" обычно не используется. Только в группе, где **все** друг друга хорошо знают.

Comment: Пусть здесь и не профессионалы-журналисты, но с детских лет большинство из нас понимает, что спорт и физкультура, спорт и фитнес, спорт и танцы(не спортивные), спорт и асаны(йога) и тому подобные вещи совсем не одно и то же. Спорт предполагает СОРЕВНОВАНИЯ, а прочие перечисленные занятия - средства самоусовершенствования, улучшающие здоровье, фигуру, тонус и так далее. В предложенном тексте имеется в виду все же фитнес, диета, зарядка, бег трусцой и много еще чего, но спорт - не просматривается. Может быть в Польше или где-то еще любая физкультура называется спортом, мне это кажется неверным.

Comment: @Варяг-91 Не думаю, что тут идет речь о физкультуре. Гимнастика ушу - это спорт? Бодибилдинг? Альпинизм? Экстремальные виды? Мы просто привыкли, что спорт - это только то, чем  на олимпиадах занимаются. Вопрос о том, является ли фитнес спортом активно осуждается, он не зависит от того, где мы находимся. Судя по всему, автор считает спортом, нет причин ему в то отказывать. Мы же не статью в той же википедии правим, мы помогаем студенту (иностранному!) с русским языком освоиться.

Comment: @behemothus  Не могу согласиться.Возможно дело именно в русском языке и нашей терминологии, ведь физкультура это чисто русское понятие, это слово на другие языки переводится условно, например на английский можно перевести как physical education, на польский -  wychowanie fizyczne и т.д. Но за русским термином "физическая культура" стоит вполне определенное содержание: это не спорт, это не требует достижения пределов человеческих возможностей, не требует соревновательности, это нужно для улучшения здоровья, тогда как спорт, иногда, губит здоровье. В русской среде фитнес и ушу - не спорт.